# Programa en Pascal no toma un archivo y trabaja con datos distintos a los proporcionados

Tags: pascal

Tengo un programa en Pascal y requiero que tome un archivo en concreto, no lo toma y trabaja con datos distintos a los proporcionados.

El archivo a usar es el siguiente:

```
1000000005|1000000005|1000000001|Experimento 1|85.38|propiedades 1|310.25
1000000005|1000000005|1000000004|Experimento 2|88.17|propiedades 2|284.76
1000000005|1000000005|1000000007|Experimento 3|92.81|propiedades 3|428.47
1000000005|1000000008|1000000002|Experimento 4|86.12|propiedades 4|382.86
1000000005|1000000008|1000000005|Experimento 5|91.04|propiedades 5|307.01
1000000010|1000000011|1000000003|Experimento 6|96.38|propiedades 6|328.47
1000000010|1000000011|1000000006|Experimento 7|89.27|propiedades 7|438.12
1000000010|1000000014|1000000008|Experimento 8|84.12|propiedades 8|297.93
1000000010|1000000014|1000000011|Experimento 9|93.76|propiedades 9|362.78
1000000010|1000000014|1000000014|Experimento 10|89.91|propiedades 10|491.62
1000000015|1000000017|1000000009|Experimento 11|88.61|propiedades 11|492.21
1000000015|1000000017|1000000012|Experimento 12|84.56|propiedades 12|473.29
1000000015|1000000017|1000000015|Experimento 13|90.67|propiedades 13|417.16
1000000015|1000000020|1000000017|Experimento 14|97.23|propiedades 14|318.46
1000000015|1000000020|1000000020|Experimento 15|93.45|propiedades 15|307.91
```

El código es el siguiente:

```
program LabPascalG10;

    type
    muestras = record
    CodDep: LongInt;
    CodExp: LongInt;
    CodMue: LongInt;
    Nom: string[50];
    Riq: Real;
    Prop: string[100];
    Peso: Real;
    end;

    salida = record
    CodMue: LongInt;
    Nom: string[50];
    Riq: Real;
    Prop: string[100];
    Peso: Real;
    end;

    var
    ArchM: file of muestras;
    ArchS: file of salida;
    RegM: muestras;
    RegS: salida;
    SecSal: Text; // para aclarar q es un txt no un file
    SC: char;
    ResgDep: LongInt;
    ResgExp: LongInt;
    n: LongInt;
    resg: LongInt;
    resgsec: LongInt;
    totdep: integer;
    totexp: integer;
    porcriq: Real;
    i: integer;

    procedure CorteExp;
    begin
    writeln('     ', ResgDep, '     ', '             |', '     ', ResgExp, '     ', '          |', 
    '     ', totexp);
    totdep := totdep + totexp;
    totexp := 0;
    ResgExp := RegM.CodExp;
    end;

    procedure CorteDep;
    begin
    CorteExp;
    writeln('     ', ResgDep, '     ', '             |', '     ', '    -     ', '     ', '          
    |', '     ', totdep);
    totdep := 0;
    ResgDep := RegM.CodDep;
    end;

    function Conversion(a: shortint): char;
    begin
    case a of
        0: Conversion := '0';
        1: Conversion := '1';
        2: Conversion := '2';
        3: Conversion := '3';
        4: Conversion := '4';
        5: Conversion := '5';
        6: Conversion := '6';
        7: Conversion := '7';
        8: Conversion := '8';
        9: Conversion := '9';
    else
        Conversion := '0'; // para q tenga un valor inicial la conversion
    end;
    end;

    procedure SecuenMue;
    begin
    n := 1000000000;
    resgsec := RegM.CodMue; // queres trabajar con mue no con rep
    repeat
        resg := resgsec div n;
        SC := Conversion(resg);
        write(SecSal, SC);
        resgsec := resgsec mod n;
        n := n div 10;
    until (n = 1);
    end;

    begin
    writeln('Ingrese un porcentaje de riqueza con el cual desee armar el archivo de salida');
    readln(porcriq);
    assign(ArchM, 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\ArchivoMprueba.dat');
    {$I-}
    reset(ArchM);
    {$I+}
    if IOResult <> 0 then
    begin
        writeln('Error al abrir el archivo "ArchivoMprueba.dat". Verifica la ruta y los 
    permisos.');
        halt; // pincha todo
    end;
    read(ArchM, RegM);
    assign(ArchS, 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\ArchS.dat');
    rewrite(ArchS);
    assign(SecSal, 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\SecuenciaSalida.txt');
    rewrite(SecSal);
    totdep := 0;
    totexp := 0;
    ResgDep := RegM.CodDep;
    ResgExp := RegM.CodExp;
    writeln('       ', 'Formato Tabla', '    ');
    writeln('    Codigo del Departamento     ', '|', '    Codigo de Experimento     ', '|', '   
    Cant. Muestras');
    writeln('------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    ');
    while not EOF(ArchM) do
    begin
        if ResgDep <> RegM.CodDep then
        begin
            CorteDep;
        end
        else
        begin
            if ResgExp <> RegM.CodExp then
            begin
                CorteExp;
            end
            else
            begin
                totexp := totexp + 1;
                if RegM.Riq > 95 then
                begin
                    SecuenMue;
                    SC := '-';
                    write(SecSal, SC);
                    for i := 1 to Length(RegM.Nom) do
                    begin
                        SC := RegM.Nom[i];
                        write(SecSal, SC);
                    end;
                    SC := '/';
                    write(SecSal, SC);
                end;
                if RegM.Riq >= porcriq then
                begin
                    RegS.CodMue := RegM.CodMue;
                    RegS.Nom := RegM.Nom;
                    RegS.Riq := RegM.Riq;
                    RegS.Prop := RegM.Prop;
                    write(ArchS, RegS);
                end;
                read(ArchM, RegM);
            end;
        end;
    end;
    CorteDep;
    close(ArchM);
    close(ArchS);
    close(SecSal);
    end.
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. Dices "no lo toma y trabaja con datos distintos a los proporcionados", pero no explicas a mayor detalle qué significa esto. ¿"no lo toma"?, por ejemplo, ¿hay algún error? ¿en qué momento exacto? ¿cuál es el mensaje de error? Si no hay error, ¿cuál es el comportamiento exacto que tienes y cómo es distinto del comportamiento esperado?

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás leyendo un fichero utilizando estos comandos:

```
...
assign(ArchM, 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\ArchivoMprueba.dat');
reset(ArchM);
...
read(ArchM, RegM);
ResgDep := RegM.CodDep;
...
```

Y el fichero que has colocado de prueba no tiene el formato correcto.
El fichero que has puesto es un fichero de texto y con ese código lees (o esperas leer) un fichero que tenga formato de registro correspondiente a:

```
 muestras = record
```

Haz la prueba y escribe un fichero con ese tipo de registros, por ejemplo con este código:

```
assign(ArchM, 'r:\ArchivoMprueba.dat');
rewrite(ArchM);

RegM.CodDep := 1000000005;
RegM.CodExp := 1000000005;
RegM.CodMue := 1000000005;
RegM.Nom := 'Experimento 1';
RegM.Riq := 85.38;
RegM.Prop := 'Propiedades 1';
RegM.Peso := 310.25;
write(ArchM, RegM);

RegM.Nom := 'Experimento 2';
RegM.Riq := 88.17;
RegM.Prop := 'Propiedades 2';
RegM.Peso := 284.76;
write(ArchM, RegM);

Close(ArchM);
```

Si lo pruebas e intentas verlo con el NOTEPAD verás algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si ahora pruebas a leer ese fichero generado (que sólo tiene 2 registros) con el código de tu programa, verás que los valores son los correctos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo tanto creo que tu problema es que un fichero como el que has puesto al inicio NO CUMPLE el esquema de registro que has definido (además de que es texto) y el programa al cargar los registros recupera valores incorrectos.